# Laravel redirect returns Html

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do something but I don't know what methodology I must use. I am very new to Laravel and this is also new to me.

So what I am trying to do is when data is found show the following inside Shop information cardbox. See picture.
The blade that holds that info is `shopDetails.blade.php`
now when it has no data I want it to show the `addShop.blade.php`

[image]

But I get this instead

[image]

Here is the code I have in the home blade.  (Shop Information Card)

```
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Shop Information</div>

            <div class="card-body">
                @if($message = Session::get('successs'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                        <p>{{$message}}</p>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                @endif
                @if (session('status'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        {{ session('status') }}
                    </div>
                @endif

                    {{ \App\Http\Controllers\ShopController::checkShop()}}

        </div>
```

and here is the code I have in the controller.

```
//Checks If user has added A shop
static function checkShop()
{
    $shop = DB::table('shop')->where('userid',Auth::id())->first();
    if($shop){
        return redirect()->route('shopDetails');
    }
    elseif(!$shop) {
        return redirect()->route('addShop');
    }
}
```

Why do I get that html code as a return instead of what I was hoping to get? And also is there a better method to check if a record exist show it else show a form for the user to add that record. In this case the user can add a single shop.
If the user did not add his shop yet to be prompted to add it.

So basically what I am trying to do.

If user has added a shop.
Display in that card the shop information
If user did not add a shop
display in that card the shop registration form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where to start.
You should't call controllers in your views. 
The redirect() should be used when you are posting data to controller method or you want to redirect user away from that page (for example when not authorized).

Lets say you have path /my-shop
`Route::get('/my-shop', 'ShopController@showShop')`;

in ShopController:

```
public function showShop()
{
   $shop = DB::table('shop')->where('userid',request()->user()->id);
   if($shop){
     return view('shopDetails', compact('shop')); // we are calling view with shop details
   }
     return view('addShop'); // we call the form so user can create new shop
}
```

There are many ways to do that. This is most simple I can think right now.
The shopDetails.blade.php and addShop.blade.php are views and they can't be used in route() or return or something like that.

Basically when you open a URL, Laravel checks the route, calls the controller, executes data from your method (you may collect data there) and then calls the view

Comment: wait so If I should not call a controller in a view. then should I do this process from inside the view? it would be way simpler for me to do? Ill just use a singular blade. and have it to show the details if a record exist. else show the shop registration form.  would that be better?

Comment: You shouldn't process any data in views (NEVER!). Data should be processed in controllers (or models/services) and then passed to views. Routes calls controllers, controllers process data from models and pass it to views. Of Course there is many different ways to do it and design patterns, but this is the basics. I will recommend you to look some great tutorials from https://laracasts.com/ as you need to see some basics how Laravel (or even MVC) works. It has everything you need to know from basics to advanced

Comment: ok this has helped me a lot. but not the initial answer. since with your latest  reply i will be changing the logic of my software.

Comment: "Why do I get that html code as a return instead of what I was hoping to get"? The redirect() method generates html which will redirect the user. In normal case it will throw that html to the user and he will be redirected. In your case you are "echo"-ing it with escaping (this {{ escapes html tags, this {!! don't). As it is escaped browser does not handle it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your Blade file:

```
{{ \App\Http\Controllers\ShopController::checkShop() }}
```

This outputs whatever checkShop() evaluates to, which happens to be the content from a route redirection.

You can address this by moving your `checkShop()` logic into your HomeController method, then add the code from your Blade file into the views for both of those routes.

Comment: ive done so, I moved the function to HomeController. but then I dont understand of what you asked me to do. can you pelase explain ?

Answer (score 0):

In laravel, when you return like this

`return redirect()->route('shopDetails');`

it means that your are redirecting the user to the page that has the route `shopDetails`

so What you really need to do is the following:

find your shop like you did here
`$shop = DB::table('shop')->where('userid',Auth::id())->first();`

return a view with this variable
something like:
`return('nameOfTheView')->with('shop', $shop);`

in the `nameOfTheView` blade file you should use the returned variable and show it the way you intended to

please take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views

where you can find more information about passing data to views